# Pass variable build args to docker build command

Tags: bash, azure-pipelines

Here is the docker stage:

```
  - template: ../docker-template.yml
    parameters:
      buildArgs:
        - name: Arg1
          value: $(arg1-value)
        - name: Arg2
          value: $(arg2-value)
```

docker-template.yml

```
parameters:
  buildArgs: []
stages:
  - stage: Docker
    displayName: Docker Stage
    jobs:
    - job: Docker

      steps:
      # - ${{ each arg in parameters.buildArgs }}:
      #   - bash: |
      #       buildArgString+=' --build-arg ${{arg.name}}=${{arg.value}}'
      #     displayName: "Getting Params"

      - bash: |
          ${{ each arg in parameters.buildArgs }}:
            buildArgString+=' --build-arg ${{arg.name}}=${{arg.value}}'
          echo 'buildstring=$buildArgString'
        displayName: 'build string'

      - bash: |
          cd $(sourceDirectory)
          docker build \
              -t $(registryName)/$(imageName):$(imageTag) \
              $buildArgString \
              .
        failOnStderr: true
        displayName: 'docker build'
```

Here I want to construct buildArgString based on the parameters passed and pass it to docker build command as shown. When I use this I get error

```
The directive 'each' is not allowed in this context. Directives are not supported for expressions that are embedded within a string. Directives are only supported when the entire value is an expression.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: were you able to solve this? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

As the message mentioned, you are using `each` in a wrong place. Try with below script sample:

**azure-pipelines.yml**:

```
extends:
  template: docker-template.yml
  parameters:
    buildArgs:  
      Arg1 : $(arg1-value)
      Arg2 : $(arg2-value)
```

**docker-template.yml**:

```
parameters:
- name: buildArgs 
  type: object
  default: [] 
stages:
  - stage: Docker
    displayName: Docker Stage
    jobs:
    - job: Docker
      steps:
      - ${{ each arg in parameters.buildArgs }}:
        - bash: |
            echo ${{ arg.key }}
            echo ${{ arg.value }}
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildArgStringOther]--build-arg ${{ arg.key }}=${{ arg.value }}"
          displayName: ${{ arg.key }}
        - bash: |
            echo "buildstring=$(buildArgStringOther)"
          displayName: ECHO-${{ arg.key }}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I would like to have complete string for all build args like buildString = --build-arg Arg1=Arg1Value --build-arg Arg2=Arg2Value

Comment: @anand, Does what you expected is make the **each** applied into script? So that it can double compile the parameter value and combine them? If yes, I'm afraid to say, no, this clearly does not allowed by us. Until now, the each can only work with YAML structure script.